# Why do Visual Studio 2012 and ReSharper 7 forget to display Intellisense tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense

I noticed a strange behaviour in my VS2012 installation. I use VS2012 Pro and ReSharper 7. Intellisense is just not showing code suggestions anymore. I found a few related questions in my research but they always had a slightly different setup going and none could solve my problem:

***Intellisense is working but, it's not showing the `tooltip` about selected member functions/Properties anymore.***

If I take a look at the C# Text Editor Settings in

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General
```

Most of the times the two necessary boxes **Auto List Members** and **Parameter Information** are selected. However, code suggestions in Intellisense don't work. Sometimes, when I look at the described settings, they are **unselected**.

Selecting them will make code suggestions work as in VS2010 but, only once. When I check the settings afterwards, they are most likely still selected, but code suggestions are not working anymore.

Some people suggested deleting the `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0` Folder, which did not work for me. I also tried to reset all changes, which also didn't help at all.

```
Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset
```

What in the world could make Visual Studio to just *forget* its settings and trigger such an irrational behavior?

**-edit-**

I display the code suggestions by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. However, I have to press that shortcut every time I want to see the suggestions. It has to be possible to automatically display them every time, when possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, but I kept overlooking one small ReSharper Intellisense setting. I would double check that you have `Symbol completion` on in

> ReSharper | Options | Intellisense | Completion Characters

Check out the [answer with screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462608/3619).

Comment: It was enabled all the time but by doing this I noticed that I also had to check "Completion Appearance" -> "Show Summary"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the tips, I figured out what I had missing:

I had to enable "Completion Appearance" -> "Show Summary".

I also accepted Anthonys answer because he linked to a detailed post with screenshots that shows all steps necessary. (Although the thing I had missing is not mentioned there)

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper uses it's own code suggestions that override Visual Studio ones, that could be the reason why the ones in the Visual Studio settings may be disabled. Please check ReSharper options at ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> IntelliSense. Maybe they are turned off there. If your ReSharper options are turned on but you still have no intellisense, then please ReSharper's support at http://www.jetbrains.com/support/

Comment: No, they are all set like expected. I noticed something else and updated my Question

Comment: Please recheck options on ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | Autopopup. Check that "Enable Automatic Intellisense Popup" is on. Check that on C# page for all rows it states "Display...". Check again that ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | General says ReSharper. Try to reinstall ReSharper.