# Resharper code completion tooltip not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense, code-completion

According to [this](http://resharper.blogspot.com/2007/05/code-completion-with-resharper.html) after installing resharper code completion should looks like this
[image]

but what I actualy get is (no tooltip).

[image]

Is there a way to turn on those tooltips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure you are using Resharper options to `Resharper->Options->Intellisense->General` click `Resharper`.

From *Autopopup click* Enable Automatic Intellisense popup

From *Completion Characters* check C#

From *Completion Behaviour* it should be like;

[image]

From *Completion Appearance* choose Visual Studio Intellisense font and click Show Summary.

From Parameter Info, it should be like this;

[image]

By the way, of course these are just my `Resharper` options. Here how Resharper Intellisense seems on this options;

[image]

Comment: What i changed actualy was: Checking Symbol comletion from Completion Behaviour and chacking Show Summary from Completion Appearance. Thx for help :)

Comment: ditto..  _**Symbol Completion**_ in _Completion Behavior_

Answer (score 0):

This setting might be what you are looking for:

[image: Try this setting]

Comment: This option is set for me, but it's not helping :(